# Android Gmail api get which format to be used

Tags: android, gmail-api

While using get in Gmail APi to get a message , what is the difference in giving "full" and "raw" for the format. I read that full give parsed data but i am not clear what is the actual difference. Which would be better to call if i have to retrieve the whole message like from / to / subject / body /attachment .

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

"full": **Returns the full email message data with body content parsed** in the payload field; the raw field is not used. (default)

"raw": Returns the full email message data with body content in the raw field as **a base64url encoded string**; the payload field is not used.

So bascially if you use full, you will get the body part of the email, which is not base encoded, **BUT** if you use the raw you will get the body in base64url encoded string which you further have to process.

I suggest that you use full method, since you dont have to worry about encoding part.